# Add padding to bordered paragraph

Tags: border, microsoft-word-2008

How can I add cell padding (term related to HTML) to a paragraph in Word 2008 (for Mac).

Here is a screenshot of how my paragraph looks:
[image: Paragraph]

How can I add space between the border and the characters?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Cell padding" as such does not exist in Word, but you can try these:
(I have Word <strike>2007</strike> 2010 for Windows right now, but the commands should be similar)

- Open Borders and Shading  dialog (Ribbon -> Home Tab, Paragraph sub tab, click on the arrow near the "Borders" icon)
- Click on "Borders and Shading"
- Click on "Options..."
- Adjust the values in "From text"

For the left and right "padding" the "Left Indent", "Right Indent" and "Hanging Indent" handles in the ruler may help (View Tab - > Show/Hide -> Ruler if the ruler is not visible)

<strike>(Unable to upload images from my workplace. Will upload from home later today)</strike>

Edit: Added images
(realized after 3 years, screenshots from Word 2010, instructions pretty much the same)
[image: borders and shading]
[image: options]

Answer (score 0):

In word 2013 I tried the options... dialog box approach but didn't see any change in the resulting padding. I was able to add a border to the style declaration, using the same color, and it gave the effect I was hoping for, with more padding around the text. I had to adjust the left and right margins of the style a bit, too, to get the edges to line up where I wanted them.